# Browser cookie expiration reliability

Tags: ajax, html, cookies, session-cookies

I have an AJAX HTML5 App and I am setting a few cookies with expiration dates of 5 seconds, 2 minutes, and 3 months.

#### THE 5 SECOND COOKIE

The first cookie is designed to prevent AJAX requests from happening if it exists.  This will prevent the server from being excessively hit by the user.

#### THE 2 MINUTE COOKIE

The second cookie does the opposite.  When this cookie expires (doesn't exist) an AJAX request is made to refresh the cookies.  This way the user always sees up to date data without having to do anything.

#### THE 3 MONTH COOKIE

The third is used to store user sessionID and other information (it tells the server who is logged in).

My question is, are browser cookie expirations accurate (ie. +/- 10 seconds) or are there large variations that could make this a bad idea?

Comment: Would not using a JS variable/timer do the job here? For the 3-month cookie - never trust the client, always validate against the server.

Comment: The problem with a JS timer is that if a user hits browser refresh repeatedly this won't work, but a cookie will.  The page is designed to load and then make AJAX calls IF the cookie is NOT there.  The page load is simple, the AJAX calls are more CPU/Network intensive which is why I want to minimize them.  And Yes, I am validating my '3 month cookie' against the DB.

Comment: You could delay the first request by 5 seconds on load, eliminating the need for one cookie. Also, what if the user turns off cookies completely?